# prom-client metrics returning negative value on prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, prom-client

I am running the prom-client query "http_request_duration_ms_sum" on prometheus, everytime I run this query it return's a negative value.

eg:- http_request_duration_ms_sum{code="200", instance="x.x.x.x", job="node_exporter", method="get", route="/v1/api"}   -9

Not sure why I am getting negative value while running this metrics. Whereas when I run "http_request_duration_ms_count", I get a positive count of value. Is there any way to fix this or what might be causing it to give negative value.